solr search is not working when we use `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` and wanted to search chinese character
I do have solr schema configuration for field "test" having "text" type and for it we have used solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory
Now data get indexed in solr for this "test" field but when we try to search it, I am not able to get result using solr query like below
field:(（第二期）) /  field:(（第二期）*)

For example: input value : （第二期） being index but when we try to search it than not able to get result.
I have tried to use solr.ShingleFilterFactory using query analyser but won't help here.
Any suggestions to fix the same ?
Thanks in advance !

What is the definition of the text type you've used for the field? There are several different types of text fields in the default schema, such as text_en, etc. You probably want to define your own type based on the rules described in https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/language-analysis.html#traditional-chinese / simplified chinese / etc. there depending on what your requirements are.

We are using tex type independent of language. Here data got indexed but in result I am not able to get data. If we try to search with removing ( from value than its working fine but not for whole word.

If you don't have proper tokenization for that specific language, you can't assume that searching will match what you're looking for either, since it might have been broken up following very different rules than what you could expect. Include your analysis chain for the field in your question, and try to use the language specific tokenizers and filters depending on what you're trying to achieve. If the parenthesis are part of your value, you'll have to escape them properly when searching as well, as they have special meaning in Solr syntax.

You can use the Analysis page under the Solr admin panel to see exactly where your indexed and searched content / tokens differ and why you're not getting the hit you're expecting for the field type / indexed / queried values.
